# Can Travis-CI generate automatically and push JavaDoc?

Tags: java, maven, github, javadoc, travis-ci

I've a project which use Travis-CI for continuous integration. This is a Java project using Maven, hosted on Github. But I don't have the generation of the documentation :

```
after_success:
  - javadoc -sourcepath src/mail/java/*.java -d doc/ marche
```

We have all classes commented like JavaDoc. But Travis won't execute the last command :

```
$ javadoc -sourcepath src/mail/java/*.java -d doc/ marche
Loading source files for package marche...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package marche
Constructing Javadoc information...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package marche
javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
1 error
2 warnings
```

But I don't understand what is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line was successful...

```
#Génération de la JavaDoc
after_success:
  - javadoc -private -sourcepath "src/main/java:src/main/ressources:src/test/java" -d /Users/pyrrha/IdeaProjects/aidons-les-fermiers/doc  marche.traitement.produits marche.traitement.marche marche.traitement.label marche.traitement.production marche.traitement.participant marche.traitement.exceptions
```